# VSIX flavored project that targets .NET Standard and uses the new csproj format

Tags: c#, .net-standard, vsix

I have an existing VSIX that hosts my custom flavored project type, which is based on a classic C# DLL Library project.

Everything is working fine. The only problem is that the csproj is still in the traditional format, which means it targets .NET v4.7 and uses the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` tag to tell the VS/MSBuild its project type, which in turn activates the additional features that I coded in the VSIX.

I would now like to transition to the new csproj format, used by .NET Standard libraries. However, this new format doesn't recognize the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` tag. How can I bind it to my flavored project type, then?

Does it involve shipping a custom SDK, as well? If so, where can I find info on how to do that? Official documentation is extremely scarce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I will have to transition my COM-based flavored project to the new [CPS](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem), which allows me to declare various capabilities that tie the final csproj to my VSIX implementation. I find that all this is currently still very poorly documented, but I'm slowly getting along.